# How Do I Verify and Capture the Contents of an InputStream in JUnit Mockito?

Tags: junit, mockito

I have the following setup:

```
public interface CommandRunner
{
    void run(String cmd, InputStream is) throws IOException;
}

public class CommandRunnerInputFile
{
  private final CommandRunner commandRunner;
  
  public CommandRunnerInputFile(CommandRunner commandRunner) {
    this.commandRunner = commandRunner;
  }
  
  public void run(String command, File inputFile) throws IOException {
    try (FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile)) {
      this.commandRunner.run(command, is);
    }
  }

}

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TestCommandRunnerInputFile
{
  @Mock CommandRunner commandRunner;
  
  @Captor ArgumentCaptor<InputStream> inputStream;

  
  private CommandRunnerInputFile commandRunnerInputFile;

  @BeforeEach
  void initService() {
    commandRunnerInputFile = new CommandRunnerInputFile(commandRunner);
  }
  
  @Test
  public void testHappyPath() throws IOException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("MyTestInputFile.txt").getFile());

    commandRunnerInputFile .run("MyApplication.exe", file);
    
    verify(commandRunner).run(eq("MyApplication.exe"), inputStream.capture());
    assertEquals('c', (char)inputStream.getValue().read());
  }
}
```

When I run this test, it fails with the following Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:207)
```

This make sense to me since, during the execution of the method, the underlying `FileInputStream` is closed when it has completed execution.  That is to say, at the point in time that the `FileInputStream` is captured by Mockito, it is open, but by the time I verify that it was passed (and attempt to verify its contents) it is closed.  What can I do not to simply capture the `InputStream` object itself, but actually capture its contents for verification?

Answer (score 0):

An ArgumentCaptor will not help here, as the Stream will most probably be closed already, e.g. from try-with-resources. So you will have to catch the content during the test with a mock:

```java
final StringBuilder actualContent = new StringBuilder();
when(myMock.doSomethingWithAnInputStream(any()).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
    final InputStream is = invocation.getArgument(0); 
    actualContent.append(CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    return "foo";
  });

// ... run your tests ...

verify(myMock).doSomethingWithAnInputStream(any()); // can be omitted if only one arg
assertEquals("this should be in the stream", actualContent.toString());
```

As your method returns a void, the mocking looks a bit different:

```java
doAnswer(invocation -> {
    final InputStream is = invocation.getArgument(1); 
    actualContent.append(CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    return null;
  }).when(commandRunner).run(anyString(), any());
```

I used Guava to get the InputStream content, but you can also use Apache IOUtils or one of the many other options [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/how-do-i-read-convert-an-inputstream-into-a-string-in-java).